# Git keeps prompting me for credentials

Tags: git, github

I have a local repo that I am trying to push to a github repo I created.
In my github account I've created a new ssh key with the contents of `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | pbcopy`

These steps I've done in my local repo:

```
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin https://github.com/user/shop.git
git push -u origin main
```

on the final step I get prompted for my Github Username/Password but this doesn't work anymore. When I fill in my credentials I get the error message:

> remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/managing-remote-repositories#switching-remote-urls-from-https-to-ssh

Comment: you can use ssh instead of https connection. it can avoid this authentication popup

Comment: What you're doing makes no sense. Making an SSH key and using an https URL are _opposites_.

Answer (score 3):

indeed, you can either use ssh (which I prefer) or use personal access token. in your case, since your remote is https url, use personal access token.

you can find all details you need [here](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/managing-your-personal-access-tokens#creating-a-fine-grained-personal-access-token) about it.

once you generated one, use it instead of password

if you want to push using ssh, go to repo on the clone tap choose the ssh option, the link of it starts with `git@github.com<the-rest>`. get back to the repo and change the remote url
i.e:

`git remote set-url <your url remote name> <the repo ssh link you copied>`.

in most cases the remote is named origin so 
`git remote set-url origin <paste here the link>`

then try again to push

Answer (score 2):

You created an SSH key, but then you add the HTTPS URL as your origin:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/user/shop.git
```

This won't use SSH which is why git asks for your credentials.

Instead, use an SSH URL:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:user/shop.git
```

You can copy the correct url from the web page for the github repo:

[image]

Click on Code then the SSH tab in the above screenshot. Then click the copy button.